# openstack nova have a long startup after the fast created volume

Tags: iscsi, openstack, openstack-nova, cinder, nova

i have reinstalled OpenStack with the newest version (Yoga) and all base modules. The system is running fine but the time between the creation of the volume and the startup ist very long with ~10 minutes. It's probably caused by the following message:

2022-05-30 17:49:02.266 43701 DEBUG os_brick.utils [req-34543724-269f-4fc9-b231-6efc0edaeda4 9e3321d396e74731bcba2cc52c459a6f - - default default] ==> **get_connector_properties: call** "{'root_helper': 'sudo nova-rootwrap /etc/nova/rootwrap.conf', 'my_ip': '10.20.0.26', 'multipath': False, 'enforce_multipath': True, 'host': 'pslos02', 'execute': None}" trace_logging_wrapper /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/os_brick/utils.py:167

2022-05-30 17:57:46.524 43701 DEBUG os_brick.initiator.connectors.lightos [req-34543724-269f-4fc9-b231-6efc0edaeda4 9e3321d396e74731bcba2cc52c459a6f - - default default] LIGHTOS: did not find dsc, continuing anyway. get_connector_properties /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/os_brick/initiator/connectors/lightos.py:78

2022-05-30 17:57:46.524 43701 DEBUG os_brick.initiator.connectors.lightos [req-34543724-269f-4fc9-b231-6efc0edaeda4 9e3321d396e74731bcba2cc52c459a6f - - default default] LIGHTOS: no hostnqn found. get_connector_properties /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/os_brick/initiator/connectors/lightos.py:86

2022-05-30 17:57:46.525 43701 DEBUG os_brick.utils [req-34543724-269f-4fc9-b231-6efc0edaeda4 9e3321d396e74731bcba2cc52c459a6f - - default default] <== **get_connector_properties: return (524257ms)** {'platform': 'x86_64', 'os_type': 'linux', 'ip': '10.20.0.26', 'host': 'pslos02', 'multipath': False, 'initiator': 'iqn.1993-08.org.debian:01:a4b5157f8afe', 'do_local_attach': False, 'uuid': '0dadf929-c171-45ba-9fa1-dbfad84f86d0', 'system uuid': 'b06bd258-d033-5a33-c0a9-123456789000'} trace_logging_wrapper /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/os_brick/utils.py:194

The tgt config files (iscsi) in the /var/lib/cinder/volumes/ are also there after ~10 minutes.

The returns with the long times (greater than 50000ms) comes by every calls.

The hosts have no load and are completely clean.  What can i do?